# It is possibile to send variable from docker env to yml file in spring project?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, docker

I want to set variables in my spring project `YML configuration` from docker `environment variable` without using Docker Compose.

Comment: something like this? `docker run -e TEST=hallo alpine env | grep TEST`

Answer (score 0):

To use an environment variable in your spring project, first, you need to set in your docker container.

**Set ENV in Docker Container:**

`Docker run -e LOGGING_LEVEL_ROOT="info" -e PROFILE="production" -it your_image`

Now, You can use `LOGGING_LEVEL_ROOT` in your spring project YML configuration.

```
logging:
  level:
    root: ${LOGGING_LEVEL_ROOT}
```

Or

```
spring:
  profiles: ${PROFILE}
```

> Note that, since the application.properties and application.yml files
>   accept Spring style placeholders (${…​}), the Maven filtering is
>   changed to use @..@ placeholders. (You can override that by setting a
>   Maven property called resource.delimiter.)

[oot-features-external-config-placeholders-in-properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-placeholders-in-properties)